# DllNotFoundException: TMPro_Plugin, working with TextMesh Pro on linux

Tags: c#, linux, unity-game-engine, text, fonts

I am trying to run font asset creator of TextMesh Pro 1.2.4 on Unity 2018.1.6f1 on Fedora 27. I've got the following errors:

I've heard that TextMesh hasn't been supported on Linux yet. Is it still true?

> DllNotFoundException: TMPro_Plugin
>   TMPro.EditorUtilities.TMPro_FontAssetCreatorWindow.DrawControls () (at
>   /root/.config/unity3d/cache/packages/packages.unity.com/com.unity.textmeshpro@1.2.4/Scripts/Editor/TMPro_FontAssetCreatorWindow.cs:704)
>   TMPro.EditorUtilities.TMPro_FontAssetCreatorWindow.OnGUI () (at
>   /root/.config/unity3d/cache/packages/packages.unity.com/com.unity.textmeshpro@1.2.4/Scripts/Editor/TMPro_FontAssetCreatorWindow.cs:266)
>   System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj,
>   System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder
>   binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo
>   culture) (at :0) Rethrow as
>   TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of
>   an invocation. System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj,
>   System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder
>   binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo
>   culture) (at :0)
>   System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj,
>   System.Object[] parameters) (at :0)
>   UnityEditor.HostView.Invoke (System.String methodName, System.Object
>   obj) (at
>   /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/HostView.cs:291)
>   UnityEditor.HostView.Invoke (System.String methodName) (at
>   /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/HostView.cs:284)
>   UnityEditor.HostView.InvokeOnGUI (UnityEngine.Rect onGUIPosition) (at
>   /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/HostView.cs:257)
>   UnityEditor.DockArea.OldOnGUI () (at
>   /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/GUI/DockArea.cs:386)
>   UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.IMGUIContainer.DoOnGUI
>   (UnityEngine.Event evt) (at
>   /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/UIElements/IMGUIContainer.cs:234)
>   UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.IMGUIContainer.HandleIMGUIEvent
>   (UnityEngine.Event e) (at
>   /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/UIElements/IMGUIContainer.cs:372)
>   UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.IMGUIContainer.HandleEvent
>   (UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.EventBase evt) (at
>   /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/UIElements/IMGUIContainer.cs:356)
>   UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.EventDispatcher.DispatchEvent
>   (UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.EventBase evt,
>   UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.IPanel panel) (at
>   /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/UIElements/EventDispatcher.cs:215)
>   UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.UIElementsUtility.DoDispatch
>   (UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel panel) (at
>   /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/UIElements/UIElementsUtility.cs:224)
>   UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.UIElementsUtility.ProcessEvent
>   (System.Int32 instanceID, System.IntPtr nativeEventPtr) (at
>   /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/UIElements/UIElementsUtility.cs:77)
>   UnityEngine.GUIUtility.ProcessEvent (System.Int32 instanceID,
>   System.IntPtr nativeEventPtr) (at
>   /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:184)
>
> llNotFoundException: TMPro_Plugin
>   TMPro.EditorUtilities.TMPro_FontAssetCreatorWindow.OnDisable () (at
>   /root/.config/unity3d/cache/packages/packages.unity.com/com.unity.textmeshpro@1.2.4/Scripts/Editor/TMPro_FontAssetCreatorWindow.cs:204)
>   UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Comment: Why downvoting for god's sake. There is no answer on internet for this and I think answer to my question will help many Unity programmers using linux. Why not writing a comment so that I know where I made a mistake??

Comment: Please use beauty text in order to show Exceptions - also use brackets for codes. Without good expression and syntax - you may receive negative votes. 

By the way, your question need to be answered - no problem on it.

Comment: Thanks Nuri for your constructive comment. I am new to Stack site. Hope that someone knows the answer.

Comment: Did you try to build the project? TextMeshPro should work in a build on Linux

Comment: Error appears on console when I try to generate a font atlas for an imported font under font asset creator. So I cant even create a text with my wanted font to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The native side of the code required to generate text is not available on Linux yet. The plugin itself should work during run-time in a build but its Editor tool is not supported on Linux. The Editor tool is only supported on Windows and Mac.

The original reason for the lack of support is because only few people use Linux when enveloping games with Unity. Also Unity Editor itself does not support Linux officially. Whatever support they have for it is still in experimental mode and there are many issues that makes it not worth using at this point.

Since TextMesh Pro is now bought by Unity, it's very likely that Linux will be supported. You should wait until Unity finally integrate it with Unity and maybe they will add support for Linux. At this moment, I think you should file for a bug report to remind Unity that this issue is still there then just use the `Text` component until they fix it. If you still want to use  TextMesh Pro, a workaround is to use VMware Workstation to run Windows or MacOS on your Linux then you can use them to create the Text Assets and export and import them as Packages in your Linux project.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification Programmer! I shall use virtual machine and do what you suggested. I also had difficult time to install a mono editor for linux but finally managed it. Do you recommend using the Unity's windows version under VM?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest developing your whole game with VM as you may run into issues caused by VM instead of Unity or your code. Also for performance reasons. I suggest you only use it for creating the assets you couldn't with TextMesh Pro in Linux Unity Eitor. I recommend Windows in VM since there's more graphics driver support than MacOs and also less issues

Comment: Unity under Linux is actually not that bad. The only thing thats bogging me is you always have to refresh the window, when the layout is changed.

Comment: @Vladius Haven't tried it yet but I've seen many posts about issues with it on both Unity and this forum. It's not matured to be used for a serious project.

Comment: @AykutKaraca If you think I answered your question, feel free to accept it by clicking on the "checkmark" icon next to it.

Comment: oh ok sorry, I didnt know I can do that. Thanks again.

Comment: Np. This is your first question and you wouldn't know that.

Comment: @Vladius I also didnt see any other problem with it and it works without a crash so far. It integrates with Visual Studio Code perfectly too. I can even debug it, which is something I wasnt able to do with Android Studio for some reason.